# Инициализация объекта

Tags: c#, ооп, winforms, windows, visual-studio

Я пишу небольшое приложение в WinForms, у меня есть класс Shtat(в отдельном файле), параметризованный конструктор которого принимает число. Пользователь вводит число в textbox, после чего создаётся объект этого класса. Итого я написал код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Shtat ob;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Number = Convert.ToInt32(txtKolvo.Text);      
        Shtat ob = new Shtat(Number);
    }
}
```

**Проблема** в том, что объект ob почему-то создаётся инициализированным только в пределах функции button1_Click, и за пределами этой функции он null. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в такой ситуации про инициализировать ob, что бы он был про инициализирован во всём классе, а не только в функции button1_Click?

Answer (score 7):

Все логично, ибо Shtat ob - это локальная переменная, которая доступна ("живет") только в пределах метода button1_click(...)

Comment: И правда ступил я чего-то, спасибо, не заметил, что я тип написал перед ob.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt пометьте ответ как правильный.